# Can't fully update the fork on GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a fork on GitHub from one of the projects and yesterday tried to update it.

Since my last update one of the submodules was split in 2 submodules (there is one extra submodule added and the old one updated to reflect the split).

So I opened the Terminal in my GNOME and did:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

as recommended in the Git{Hub} documentation.

All commands above were completed successfully.

After that I issued `git status` to verify that there is nothing outstanding left. To my surprise I saw that submodule that was split being in the `Changes not staged for commit:` area. My understanding is/was that this shouldn't happen.

So then what I did was I tried to do the obvious `git add .`. This however didn't change anything at all. I don't even have this in the staging, I still see it in the same `Changes not staged to commit` area.

What do I do at this point?

I don't want to kill the fork to re-create it, but feel like I won't have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened, but what I did is to delete the folder with the submodule and ran `git submodule update--init`.

That fixed it.